# MySQL LIKE and LIMIT

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select stuff from a database with the LIKE statement, but I would also like to LIMIT the amount of records I get out of it.

```
SELECT * FROM proizvodi WHERE `naziv` LIKE %127%
AND LIMIT 0, 10
```

The code I have is a boolean, and is not working. How to fix this?

Comment: Try to avoid `LIKE '%...` as it has not good performance. `LIKE 'XXX%` is better.

Comment: This question is better to be deleted, as it is caused by typos and unlikely to help anyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings in SQL need to be quoted and the `LIMIT` clause cannot be joined with `AND`.

```
SELECT * FROM proizvodi WHERE `naziv` LIKE '%127%' LIMIT 0, 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the documentation for the `SELECT` statement, you don't need to use AND to join your `WHERE` and `LIMIT` sections.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

`` SELECT * FROM proizvodi WHERE `naziv` LIKE %127% LIMIT 0, 10; ``

Comment: I figured it out, `LIKE %127%` needed single quotes. `LIKE '%127%'`

Answer (score 1):

SQL is *not* guaranteed to return the same results in the same order each time, unless you use an `order by`.  You code should look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM proizvodi
WHERE `naziv` LIKE %127%
ORDER BY <something>
LIMIT $start, $per_page
```

Answer (score 0):

Limit is not part of the where clause and therefore no `AND` is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM product WHERE `ProName` LIKE "%'.$searchWord.'%" LIMIT '.$this_page_first_result.', '.$results_per_page.';'
```

Comment: This answer should be deleted as it promotes SQL injection

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect,
         "SELECT * FROM proizvodi
         WHERE `naziv` LIKE %127%
         ORDER BY naziv ASC
         LIMIT 10");
```

This will limit your queries up to 10.

$start, $per_page is something to get hands later if this is a problem now.. :)

Answer (score -1):

change the query to this below
SELECT * FROM proizvodi  WHERE `naziv` LIKE %127%
LIMIT 0, 10